# adding a static route to a unix system

Tags: networking, unix, routing

I am using a UNIX compatible distribution (unfortunately I can't disclose the OS) as a router for a shared internet connection

I need to add a static route such that any HTTP request to `my.router.com` will be routed to the configuration page of the router (i.e. the user doesn't need to know the IP address of the router they are connecting to)

Is this possible? Can it be done by editing the /etc/hosts file, or using the route command?

Thanks

Comment: This question seems to conflate DNS, IP routing, and possibly HTTP proxying. It's kind of hard to figure out how to answer as-is.

Comment: any suggestions as to how I could improve it?

Comment: First off, routes are for routing across either IPv4 or IPv6 networks, not domain names. The purpose of a static route is to specify a gateway to send traffic to when the destination IP of a packet needs to go somewhere more specific than an existing route. It sounds like you are trying to null route traffic to a specifc website for everyone that is connected to that router. In order to better answer your question, you should try to be more descriptive about the end result that you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You could begin by naming the protocol(s) involved, before the word "request".

Comment: Are you trying to do something like a porn filter, where any time anyone on the LAN behind your Unix-based router tries to go to certain websites, they get your Unix box's built in web server, which serves a "Sorry, you're not allowed to see that website" page?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @Spiff not exactly, but such a mechanism would work. I want any request to a single URL to be redirected, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to add a static route such that any HTTP request to my.router.com will be routed to the configuration page of the router (i.e. the user doesn't need to know the IP address of the router they are connecting to)

"Routing" works on the IP layer only.  It doesn't care about anything above it, such as the application layer, which is where HTTP is, or the transport layer, where the concept of "ports" and "services" (i.e. HTTP is on port 80, which is one way to tell that type of traffic from other traffic) exist.

> Is this possible? Can it be done by editing the /etc/hosts file

You can add an entry "my.router.com" to your `hosts` file.  It will cause "my.router.com" to resolve to the IP address you specify in that file IF your system is configured to use that file for DNS lookups before DNS (look at `nsswitch.conf`(?) to configure that on Linux).

Of course, if a user enters an IP address directly, such as `http://256.40.40.1` the `hosts` file and anything DNS based doesn't work.

> or using the route command?

What you could do with the `route` command is create a static `/32` route for the IP address of the real `my.router.com` and have it go to your localhost adapter.  This would cause traffic destined for `256.40.40.1`, if that was the real IP of `my.router.com`, to go to `127.0.0.1`.  Of course, if `my.router.com` changes their IP you have to update this manually.